# Add Qt private headers to CMake project

Tags: qt, cmake

How should I add Qt private headers to my CMakeLists.txt ?

```
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick QuickPrivate REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Quick QuickPrivate REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the private API of the "QTMOD" submodule then you must include only the headers using the variable:

```
Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}QTMOD_INCLUDE_DIRS
```

In your case:

```
include_directories(${Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}Quick_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

<sub>**Note:** Not exist `QuickPrivate`</sub>

Answer (score 5):

**Previously accepted answer is invalid as of recently.** Qt6 has a special CMake target for enabling private headers. You just need to link against it, i.e., `WidgetsPrivate` is the target name for `Qt Widgets Module`'s private headers:

```
target_link_libraries(untitled PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::WidgetsPrivate)
```